# Bugzilla - UNCONFIRMED

Tags: bugzilla

We have a simple system, running Bugzilla 5.0.6. One Product, ProductA, multiple components. Two users, User1 & User2, no groups.

User1 is a member of conconfirm, User2 is not. ProductA is set to "Allow UNCONFIRMED Bugs"

User1 creates a bug for ProductA and the status defaults to CONFIRMED. All well and good.

User2 creates a bug for ProductA and the status still defaults to CONFIRMED, even though they are not a member of the in built canconfirm group.

I'm missing something fundemental here, how can I set up Produts / Users in Bugzilla so that certain users can raise bugs but are raised as UNCONFIRMED, whilst other users can raise bugs for the same product but raise them as CONFIRMED?

Comment: One thing is what an user can do, and other what the system defaults to. If the system defaults all tickets to "confirmed", regardless of who create it, then it creates it as those. If you want to test, create a unconfirmed ticket and ask both users to set it to confirmed.

Comment: User1 created a bug and marked it as UNCONFIRMED. User2 was able to mark this bug as CONFIRMED even though not part of the canconfirm group. As I say I'm missing soemthing fundemental here. Thanks for the suggestion.